# Running a permutation test with different sample sizes in R

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, inference

Apply the permutation test with statistic $t = \bar{x} − \bar{y}$ to Example A, where $x$ and $y$ respectively refer to measurements with and without honey.
The data is

[image]

I just don't know how to account for the different sample sizes. Do I throw out some of the values or do I have to approximate the missing values with the mean? Originally learned it for equal sample sizes. With the equal sample sizes we subtracted column 1 from column 2. The original code for the equal sample size is

```
d <- A-B#subrract columns A from B
n <- length(d)#length of column
d.perm <- matrix(abs(d),n,1000)#create a matrix with a 1000 copies of d
d.perm <- d.perm*sign(runif(1000*n)-.5)#randomly generate + or - signs
d.bar <- apply(d.perm,2,mean)#get the mean of each column
mean($d.bar<mean(d)$)))#get a p-value of those $d.bar<mean(d)$
```

Need to account for the different sample sizes in the code. Thanks

Here is my updated code.

```
honey=c(19,12,9,17,24,24) 
no_honey=c(14,8,4,4,11,11)
t_stat=mean(honey)-mean(no_honey) 
combine=c(honey,no_honey) 
difference=rep(0,924) 
for (i in c(1:924)) { 
y=sample(combine) 
t_stat1=mean(y[1:6])-mean(y[7:12])
difference[i]=t_stat1 } 
p_value=sum(abs(difference)>abs(t_stat))/924
```

Comment: The question *tells* you what statistic to use. You're not doing what it says to do. In particular, subtracting as if the data were paired makes no sense when the data are NOT paired. Do what it tells you to do. There's nothing to answer here.

Comment: Oh but I need to get the differences first between the two groups. SInce they have different sample sizes how do I do that? Thats the exact code from an example in class similar to this but the data had equal sample sizes.

Comment: Let me try again. What statistic does it say to use, *exactly*?

Comment: yes I know the sample mean of first group subtracted from the sample mean of the second group.

Comment: Can you compute the sample mean of the first group?

Comment: "*I need to get the differences first between the two groups*" --  you really need to NOT do that Your problem is you're trying to use code for a *paired* test. Don't do that. Almost every line of your code is not suitable to the current problem. The general ideas of permutation tests carry over, but the specific details don't.

Comment: Oh ok. I guess I forgot to overlook that.  Well the sample mean for the first group is 110/9 and second group is 17/2. Take away both you get 67/18.

Comment: Now you need to figure out how to get new samples of size 9 and 6. Imagine the null was true and all the data came from the same population. Would it matter which 6 observations you had labelled as group 1?

Comment: Ah ok switch some of the numbers around. I think there are 9 choose 6 combinations I think.

Comment: Nope. How many observations are there altogether?

Comment: Oops 15 choose 9 =5005 different ways. Now I have to figure how to generate random samples of 9 and 6 and calculate the mean.

Comment: There's a bunch of ways to do that in R. If you knew what was in the first sample, could you figure out the mean of the second sample?

Comment: Anyway, I'll put an answer along the lines of the comments

Comment: Thanks I kind of got an idea. Under the null, just combine the data in a vector, resample it, and calculate the mean for the first 9 elements and last 6 elements. Subtract them and then store that result in another vector. Take the mean of all the resampled means less than the original data and that should be the p-value I think.

Comment: That would be a one-tailed p-value; if your alternative is one tailed that might work. You should probably add the `self-study` tag (whose [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) explains why I'm answering the way I am).

Comment: So you mean just take the mean of all the means<t est statistc and if its less than alpha/2 or is the mean of all means >test statistic greater than alpha/2  then we reject the null hypothesis? I added the self study tag as well.

Comment: Consider the "as, or more extreme" part of what a p-value is. It depends on how you set up your test but normally if you're doing a two-tailed test of difference in means you'd define "as extreme" in the other tail as "equally as far the other side of 0", which may not correspond to the same tail proportion in each tail (though it will often be similar). Looking at the same issue another way, a two-tailed test could be done in terms of $|\bar{x}-\bar{y}|$ and then both tails are at the high end of the new statistic.

Comment: Updated it in the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some assumptions if you are going to do a permutation test (otherwise nothing will be exchangeable under the null hypothesis).  If fact, you didn't even state that these were two independent simple random samples from two populations - as far as I know these could be two time series.

ASSUME (maybe):  Honey values are independent and identically distributed.  No honey values are independent and identically distributed.  The two samples are also independent of each other.

Let the Honey values have distribution F(t) and the No Honey values have distribution F(t-$\theta$).  Then $H_o: \theta = 0$ vs $H_a:  \theta \not= 0$.  Note that $\theta$ is the difference of the two population means (assuming they HAVE means...which is reasonable).

Then, under $H_o$, you can mix the two groups together, then split them randomly into samples of size 9 and 6, compute the difference of the means, then repeat.  This will give you the null distribution of the difference of the means.  You might consider:

temp = sample(c(Honey,NoHoney),replace=FALSE)

resample_honey = temp[1:9]

resample_nohoney = temp[10:15]

null[i] = mean(resample_honey) - mean(resample_nohoney)

Comment: Please read the [guidelines](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) on answering `self-study` questions, which call for "hints and guidance". If someone has an assignment to write some code, writing an important chunk of the the code for them seems to go beyond that level of help. The part explaining the need for assumptions is excellent, so I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The question tells you to use $\bar{x}-\bar{y}$ as a test statistic, not $\overline{x_i-y_i}$ (which is for paired observations). Indeed your code is for a paired problem, so you'll need to write new code.

Notionally, if the null hypothesis were true all 9+6 observations would be from the same population, and the group labels would be arbitrary. This suggests what you need to resample.

Comment: Student's t-Test in R: t.test(c(12,15,13,12,17,5,6,7,23),c(13,12,4,7,8,7))

Comment: @SorenHavelundWelling How does that help the OP do a *permutation test* using the difference in means as a test statistic?